# Edit Power BI (pbix) file in a text editor

Tags: powerbi

I have a very talented and thoughtful data warehouse team.  The data modeler has created columns with names that make good sense to the users.  But now I'm trying to use Power BI.  It appears to take offense at a well-modeled data mart.

On one of my tables, I have dozens of measures.  When I bring this table into Power BI, they are "columns" that have the sigma sign next to them, indicating they are implicit measures.  These appear to work OK on a Power BI report.  But now I understand why the training I attended said to create my own measures and don't use the implicit measures:  Power BI Paginated Reports (probably among other reasons).  Every measure I want to use in a paginated report must be a Power BI "measure".

All of my columns are already appropriately named.  But I can't create a measure with the same name as a column.  So the solution Power BI appears to want me to use is:

1. Right-click on the implicit measure (column)
2. Choose Rename
3. Bork the column name
4. Enter
5. Wait for Power BI to validate the entire file ("working on it...")
6. Right-click on a column in the table (because I want the measure with the table to be
   clear to the user/report developer)
7. Select "new measure"
8. Type the DAX expression for the measure
9. Wait for Power BI to validate the entire file ("working on it...")
10. Right-click on the column just converted and select "Hide"

This can become rather tedious when there are dozens or hundreds of columns to convert.

I have a partial solution:  I have written a SQL script that outputs the M expression that I can edit using regular expressions (to bork the good names already in the database) and paste into the Advanced Editor in Power Query.

I can do something similar to create the DAX expressions needed to create all of the measures.  But I don't see a way to get these expressions into the file in bulk.  **Is there a way to edit a Power BI (pbix) file without using Power BI?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your stated question, but I think you've got a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

> "columns" that have the sigma sign next to them, indicating they are implicit measures

This is not quite correct. These are not measures (measures use calculator icon) but columns that Power BI has categorized as a numeric value column that it will automatically aggregate with an implicit measure if you add it to a visual in your report (as opposed to a dimensional / categorical column).

[Implicit measures](https://radacad.com/explicit-vs-implicit-dax-measures-in-power-bi) are the automatic aggregations that are created using these sigma columns. Implicit measures are not visible in the Fields pane.

---

To more directly address your question, there are a couple of possibilities that come to mind to approach your problem.

**Option 1:**
If you want to make bulk changes to a .pbix file, then using an external tool like [Tabular Editor](https://github.com/TabularEditor/TabularEditor) (which is [directly supported in Power BI Desktop now](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/support-of-external-tools-in-power-bi-desktop-is-ga/)) is the way to go. The data model part of the .pbix file is stored in highly compressed format, which makes simple text edits not feasible. Tabular Editor has [scripting capabilities](https://docs.tabulareditor.com/te2/Useful-script-snippets.html) that can be used to do all kinds of things.

**Option 2:**
If you're only concerned about report builder and don't need the measures in your .pbix file for other purposes, then you can create whatever measures you want as part of the query itself.

When you query a Power BI dataset, the DAX query might look something like this:

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    DimTable[Column1],
    DimTable[Column2],
    DateTable[Date],
    FilterTable1,
    FilterTable2,
    "Measure1", [Measure1],
    "Measure2", [Measure2]
)
```

Suppose `[Measure1]` is an explicit measure defined as

```
Measure1 = SUM ( FactTable[Value] )
```

Instead of defining this measure in your data model and referencing it in your query, you could just define it in your query. Also, note that you can put whatever name you'd like instead of `"Measure1"`. For example, the following should work.

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    DimTable[Column1],
    DimTable[Column2],
    DateTable[Date],
    FilterTable1,
    FilterTable2,
    "Value", CALCULATE ( SUM ( FactTable[Value] ) ),
    "Amount", CALCULATE ( SUM ( FactTable[Amount] ) )
)
```

Comment: "You can use numeric value columns" -- not really.  If I simply import from the database and don't create measures, the implicit measures don't aggregate in a paginated report.  I discovered this by finding it took 17 minutes to process all 7 million detailed rows.  If I create a [explicit] measure in the data set, the aggregation occurs and I quickly get the handful or rows I was expecting.

Comment: BTW:  A Microsoft employee who is a Power BI expert verified that my problem was caused by using implicit measures.

Comment: Yes, you definitely want to aggregate your rows (using explicit measures) rather than loading all the detail rows. I guess I was hung up on why you needed to rename columns rather than create measures with distinct names. I’ll edit to suggest a couple possible workflows in a bit.

Comment: Either way, I don't want to do it in Power BI if I can avoid it.  That could take me all week.

Comment: I have edited my answer. See if either option works for you.

Comment: Option 2:  `The resultset of a query to external data source has exceeded the maximum allowed size of '1000000' rows.`  Maybe I need to import the data rather than using Direct Query?  But then it may be too big to publish.

Comment: So Report Builder is connecting to a Power BI dataset which is connecting to a data warehouse via DirectQuery? I don't think I've tried that before. I'd probably try to connect Report Builder to the data warehouse directly unless I had done a ton of not-easily-replicated data modeling work in  Power BI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237439/discussion-between-dougp-and-alexis-olson).

Comment: Accepted because the solutions provided do help with smaller stuff.  In this case, I had to not use a Power BI data set but rather get the data directly from the rdl.